Journey Builder Entry source count is zero
I have Automation that overwrites the data extension and we are using the same DE for email send via Journey builder. Some times count became zero after running the automation.
Can we set any clause in Journey to Notify us if the audience count is zero in entry criteria.

That's exactly why there is a Verification Activity in Automation Studio.
You need to edit the automation and place this activity after a Query activity and before the journey trigger.
You can use it to send an email and even stop the automation if specific conditions about the count of records in a data extension targeted by a query before are met.

You can watch a video about this from Cameron Robert:
How to use the Verification Activity in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Can we do the same operation in the Journey instead of Automation Studio??

No. This can only be done in Automation Studio

In Journey, is there anything that notify us once the journey completes?

No, there is nothing like that out of the box

Thanks for the help  Rafał Wolsztyniak. Appreciate it!
